# Having trouble moving my css image slider

Tags: html, css, notepad++

[image]

I have followed a tutorial on youtube on how to make a css image slider. I have managed to center it but am having trouble moving it up and making the border around the image. How can I do this. Thanks.

```css
.sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 height:100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0px;
 width: 300px;
 background:#808080;
 border: 3px solid #555;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 300px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
 color:#f2f2f2;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 300px;
 margin-top:30px;
 color:#e6e6e6;
 font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}


.sideimage {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

.con {
 border: 5px solid red;
 width: 700px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 300px auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-left: 300px
}

.img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 700px;
 height: 500px;
 animation: mm 15s infinite;
 -webkit-animation: mm 15s infinite;
 opacity: 0;
}
 
@keyframes mm{
 10%{opacity:1}
 45%{opacity:0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mm{
 10%{opacity:1}
 45%{opacity:0}
}


img:nth-child(0){animation-delay: 0s;-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay: 5s;-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay: 10s;-webkit-animation-delay: 10s;}


.main_image {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 300px;
 margin-top: 100px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #66b3ff;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #555;
}


li a:hover {
    background-color:#27C0FD;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<html>
<body bgcolor="#3399ff"> 

<h1> Informational Tech Site</h1>

<h2>This website is the place in which you can find all the information about what building games actually looks like in a workplace environment.
</h2>

<div class="con">
<img src="images/image slider1.png" class="img">
<img src="images/image slider 2.png" class="img">
<img src="images/image slider 3 .png" class="img">
</div>


<body>
<div class="sidebar">
 <ul>
 <div class="sideimage"><img src="images/website logo draft.png" height="70" width="110"/></div>
 
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
 <li><a href="page 2.html">page 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="page 3.html">page 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="page 4.html">page 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="page 5.html">page 5</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>




</body>
```

Comment: Here is the code I am wanting to center the image slider in the blue section. https://jsfiddle.net/wcek0eo5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what you want, just change this:

```
.con {
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 300px; /* Change 1 */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* padding-left: 300px; Change 2 */
}
```

**Change 1:** I left only margin-left because it was the only margin that you needed, remember that using `margin: 300px auto;` will set `margin: top/bottom left/right;` so it would look like:

```
margin-top: 300px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 300px;
margin-left: auto;
```

**Change 2:** I removed padding because it was pushing your border away.
Keep in mind this image to understand the usage and differences between margin and padding:

[image: Google Chrome Inspector's image explanation]

The CSS margin properties are used to generate space around elements. The margin properties set the size of the white space **OUTSIDE** the border.

The CSS padding properties are used to generate space around content. The padding properties set the size of the white space between the element content and the element border.

**My opinion**

I can see that you are learning web developing, so let me suggest using and learning bootstrap.

**Bootstrap:** http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

You will learn how to use a grid to create more organized and responsive themes, and you will have the power of it's javascript ready to use components.

You can learn from scratch here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Plus it also has a carousel and it's great!
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I have made these changes and this is the result. https://imgur.com/LDD1Yo2 How can I center the image slider in the blue section?

Comment: Here is the code I have just used a different image. https://jsfiddle.net/wcek0eo5/ I am wanting to center the image slider in the blue section.

Comment: You need to add a new wrapper so you can center the slider inside. Your ex. updated: https://jsfiddle.net/xwazzo/fc1u3xpf/2/  

I really suggest learning bootstrap, because this is getting really messy and we are solving but not with good practices.

Please select my answer If you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
div.con img{border:5px solid red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following modified HTML and CSS to get your required output.

HTML::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>
<body bgcolor="#3399ff"> 
<div class="main-container">
<h1> Informational Tech Site</h1>
<h2>This website is the place in which you can find all the information about what building games actually looks like in a workplace environment.
</h2>
<div class="con">
<img src="images/image slider1.png" class="img">
<img src="images/image slider 2.png" class="img">
<img src="images/image slider 3 .png" class="img">
</div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
<div class="sideimage"><img src="images/website logo draft.png" height="70" width="110"/></div>

<li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
<li><a href="page 2.html">page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="page 3.html">page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="page 4.html">page 4</a></li>
<li><a href="page 5.html">page 5</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS::

```
.sidebar {
position: fixed;
height:100%;
left: 0;
top: 0px;
width: 300px;
background:#808080;
border: 3px solid #555;
}

.main-container{
float: right;
width: 75%;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
/*padding-left: 300px;*/
font-size: 50px;
font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
color:#f2f2f2;
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
/*padding-left: 300px;*/
margin-top:30px;
color:#e6e6e6;
font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}


.sideimage {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 30px;
}

.con {
border: 5px solid red;
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
/*padding-left: 300px*/
}

.img {
position: absolute;
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
animation: mm 15s infinite;
-webkit-animation: mm 15s infinite;
opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes mm{
10%{opacity:1}
45%{opacity:0}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes mm{
10%{opacity:1}
45%{opacity:0}
}


img:nth-child(0){animation-delay: 0s;-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay: 5s;-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay: 10s;-webkit-animation-delay: 10s;}


.main_image {
text-align: center;
/*padding-left: 300px;*/
margin-top: 100px;
}


ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 300px;
background-color: #66b3ff;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #000000;
padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
border-bottom: 3px solid #555;
}


li a:hover {
background-color:#27C0FD;
color: #000000;
}
```